# Reset TinyMCE box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I am using [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) editor. I want to clear the content inside the editor box with some button click present on my form.

Can you let me know how to do so?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can be easily done (no need to use the slow jQuery tinymce build) using the following code as onclick-action of your button:

```
// 'content' is tinymce default,
// but if your textarea got an ID that is the one you need!
var my_editor_id = 'content';

// set the content empty
tinymce.get(my_editor_id).setContent('');
```

Comment: For more clarity, `my_editor_id` should really be named `my_textarea_id`. When I read **editor** I think of the tinymce editor :-)

Comment: well, both ids are identical (if the editor source html element got an id set)

Comment: where does this code go though?  it would be nice to place a button right next to the available buttons upon which runs this snippet of code `tinymce.get('content').setContent(''); `

Comment: you may call this code from anyplace in the main document

Comment: In my case I needed to call this inside a `setTimeout` anonymous function with a timeout of 0. Otherwise it didn't work and I got all sorts of errors in the JS console for some reason. Just thought I should mention it.

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper: thx for pointing this out. The tinymce behaviour might have changed concernign this issue from version 3 to version 4.

Answer (score 2):

From the [TinyMCE jQuery Plugin documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/jQuery_Plugin), can be easily found from the page you linked:

```
// Will change the contents of an textarea with the ID "someeditor"
$('#someeditor').html('Some contents...');

// Will change the contents all text areas with the class tinymce
$('textarea.tinymce').html('Some contents...');

// Gets the contents from a specific editor
alert($('#someeditor').html());
```

Try setting it to empty string, might be just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in **clearing the content** of the editor you can use:
**tinymce.get('#editorId').setContent('');** // like others have suggested

However, if you'd like to reset the content and menu buttons etc. - **essentially resetting the editor altogether** you might consider using:
**tinymce.get('#editorId').init();**

Comment: Highlight the code part using back-tick ` character.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to init() tinymce editor 4.x. I tried this but I have to say it only inits the textarea of the editor, menu (buttons, etc.) and toolbar will not be reinitialised. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sets the specified content to the editor instance, this will cleanup the content before it gets set using
the different cleanup rules options.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#name_of_your_textarea').val('');
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your solution solves the OP's problem: you're resetting the contents of the underlying textarea, not that of the tinymce editor.